# Logging Mass Transit with Serilog

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, serilog, masstransit

I have this console application project where I use **EF6** with postgresql, **Quartz** and **Mass Transit** and as DI I use **Castle Winsdor**. The goal of the project is to check periodically a folder (or folders) for new files and process them (mostly by storing data in the DataBase).

I wanted to use a logging service for debug purposes and I came across Serilog. I managed to add it to Quartz and EF, but I have issues adding it to Mass Transit.

What I've done so far:

I've added Serilog as Logging for `Castle.Core.Logging`

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Auto(Classes.FromThisAssembly());
    var factory = container.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();
    container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(factory as SerilogFactory));
}
```

And then I added it to EF using a Logger Interceptor and to Quartz using Serilog settings.

But now I want to add it to my MassTransit Automatonymous, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

First of all, I tried to add Serilog from the BusControl Configuration:

```cs
BusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UseSerilog(Log.Logger);  //Where `Log.Logger` is the Serilog Logger
});
```

But then I encountered a `MassTransit.Logging.ILogger` exception that was also [discussed here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1620).

In that thread I found that I should add Serilog (or any other logger) [in a different way](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/478cae22d0df2a15033843b89cc50ffc48c25664/docs/getting-started/upgrade-v6.md), by configuring the MassTransit `LogContext` like so
`LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(loggerFactory);`. But the thing is, they are now using
`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` and I cannot convert my logger from `Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger` to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`.

Is there any way to use my Castle.Core.Logging logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` NuGet package, which adds `ILoggerFactory` support to *Serilog*. You can pass that interface to configure MassTransit via:

```cs
LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(loggerFactory);
```

MassTransit does not use any Castle facilities, however, there is a NuGet package for configuring MassTransit using ]Castle Windsor](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/castlewindsor.html).

*Update: You can view a sample Serilog configuration in [this sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Twitch/blob/master/src/Sample.Service/Program.cs#L39)*

Comment: This helped me get rid of the errors, but nothing is logged. Do you have an example of the output I should be getting from when I publish an event for a state machine?

Comment: You need this method called prior to creating the bus, or within the bus configuration block so that it's available once the bus closure execution completes. And you can specify the logging level within Serilog (`.MinimumLevel.Override("MassTransit", LogEventLevel.Debug`).

Comment: Yes, I thought I had that set, but apparently I reverted changes at one point and I deleted the line. Thanks a lot for the help!